# I am getting this error in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{  
   "error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported",
   "status":406
}
```

Though I used header `Content-Type`

Here is the the command I used for indexing a customer document for a customer index:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/customer/doc/1 -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"name":"abcd"}'
```

Comment: Try to add a space after the colon, i.e. `'Content-Type: application/json'`

Comment: added space,getting same error.

Comment: which version of ES are you running?

Comment: Currently I am using 6.1.3 version